# Tell which symbols are linkable in object file?

Tags: c++, c

Is there a way of viewing an object file and know which symbols can be linked to? Assuming debug info is available. I know some symbols would be undefined but I would like to know if there is a way of looking at an object file and knowing "yes I can make a call to that function or not"

Comment: Depends on your toolchain. For gcc or clang you can use the `nm` tool to list the symbols of an object file or library.

Comment: yeah so im using nm but its unclear to me which symbols can be linked to

Comment: If you call `man nm` there's an explanation of the letters used to indicate which symbols are publicly visible.

Comment: what publicly visible mean? I'm assuming linkable but that doesn't necessarily prevent link errors if the symbols undefined correct?

Comment: _"what publicly visible mean?"_ Linkable from other .o or .a files.

Comment: hmm greping the man page seems to not contain either "public" or "visible" are you sure your looking at the correct man pages?

Comment: my best guess is `nm -C --defined-only sleigh.o | perl -ne 'print if $_ =~ /\ T\ /'` but I'm just not sure if that is sufficient.

Comment: You're right. Seems I remembered wrongly about this. Though I am not sure what information you actually want to get from the symbols? The undefined references only?

Comment: so my issue is that I dont quite understand the src to a project but I can compile it in pieces and was wanting to test the functions by object file to better understand how different parts work rather than take on the entirely built library.

Comment: It's only relevant for investigation if you encounter _undefined reference_ linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the command nm in bash it will show you the table symbol of the object file.
capitalized symbols like W (global weak) T (global text) are symbols that you can use with other objects that you link to the one you use nm on.

Answer (score 0):

If you on unix check **readelf**. On windows check  **dumpbin.**